# when i install react native vision camera i will face issue when i run my app

Tags: react-native-vision-camera

PS D:\Reactnative projects\testcameraapp> npm run android

> testcameraapp@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :react-native-vision-camera
> [VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core found, Frame Processors enabled!
> 5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vision-camera'.

> [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\ziazia\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 53s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vision-camera'. > [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\ziazia\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 53s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

PS D:\Reactnative projects\testcameraapp> npm run android

> testcameraapp@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy and 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Configure project :react-native-vision-camera
> [VisionCamera] react-native-worklets-core found, Frame Processors enabled!
> 5 actionable tasks: 5 up-to-date

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-vision-camera'.

> [CXX1101] NDK at C:\Users\ziazia\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.1.8937393 did not have a source.properties file

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this ndk version

**ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).